# Differences in assigning values to a variable

Tags: python, while-loop

In Python, why are the below 2 functions different, i.e. how is this function:

```
def year (rate):
    money=100
    count=0
    while money<(2*money):
        money+=money*rate
        print ("{0:.2f}".format(money))
        count+=1
    return (count)
```

(which results in `count` having the value `10423`) different from this other function?

```
def year (rate):
    money=100
    count=0
    while money<200:
        money+=money*rate
        print ("{0:.2f}".format(money))
        count+=1
    return (count)
```

(which results in `count` having the value `11`)

If we assume that x=100, isn't x<200 the same as x<(x+x). Also, isn't x+x=200?

Answer (score 3):

`money < 2 * money` will ALWAYS be true.

Because as `money` will increase, so will `2 * money`.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the value of `money` during your loop with `money += money*rate` so it looks like you are creating an endless loop.  If you did something like this you should be start to see the results you expect:

```
def year (rate):
    money=100
    count=0
    end_limit = 2*money
    while money<(end_limit):
        money+=money*rate
        print ("{0:.2f}".format(money))
        count+=1
    return (count)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first function, if you want to compare with the original `money`, you can do something like this:

```
def year (rate):
  money=100
  orig_money = money
  count=0
  while money < (2 * orig_money):
    money+=money*rate
    print ("{0:.2f}".format(money))
    count+=1
  return (count)
  # count=10423
```

Comment: Yeap, assigning a variable to the original money is a very elegant approach to overcome the problem. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, your expression `money<(2*money)` changes and is not constant. All expressions should retain their condition in most cases to prevent an endless/infinite loop.

Try and not compare a variable to the same variable as this results in the left and right hand side of the expression both changing.

By using `money < 200`, the 200 is a **constant**. Every iteration of the loop will check against this constant and then determine to continue or break out of the loop.

Hope I have made this situation clear. :)